# Hide WinForms TreeView plus sign

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a WinForms TreeView with one main node and several sub-nodes.

How can I hide the + (plus sign) in the main node?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Treview Property: **`.ShowRootLines = false`**

When `ShowRootLines` is false, the Plus/Minus sign will not be shown for the root node, but will still show when necessary on child nodes.

With the Plus/Minus sign hidden, you might consider executing the `Expand()` method of the root node once the tree is populated.  That will make sure that the root node shows all first-level child nodes.

Note: There is a `ShowPlusMinus` property on the TreeView, but it works on *all* nodes.

Answer (score 0):

See the TreeView::ShowExpandCollapse property. Set it to false to disable the expand/collapse node indicators.

Answer (score 0):

Set SiteMapDataSource property ShowStartingNode to false. For example: