# Treeview hide [+] [-] buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, button, treeview

Does anyone know how to hide the [-] button for a treeview? The treeview will never be collapsed, and therefore I dont need the root node to have the collapse option. I know I could use a listview with a stye that indents the [0] element to act like a treeview root node. However the binding I'm using etc. kind of asks for a treeview, and I'm not sure how to access the button and disable it.

Comment: @urema - what coding language do you want the answer in - C#, VB, VC++, etc.?

Comment: See this for C# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161378/treeview-sign

Comment: Although I don't have an answer for you, I do have some suggestions pertaining to SO:
One, I'm assuming you are talking about C# because of your other questions. At this time, there is no language tag on this question.
Two, you have asked 13 questions but haven't accepted any answers. You should accept answers to your questions in order to help SO move forward.

Comment: I'm guessing C# and WPF from looking at the OPs question history. I have fixed the tags accordingly.

Comment: You should at least add tags to let people know which language or toolkit you are working with. I could as well ask "What's the translation of 'chair'?"

Comment: I have assigned the tag "C#"....please look before expressing criticisms

Comment: System.Windows.Controls.TreeView by the way! Not the winforms treeview!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work. You need to modify the ControlTemplate of the TreeViewItem, the [+] / [-] button is actually a ToggleButton inside the TreeViewItem's ControlTemplate so all you need to do is set its visibility to hidden or collapsed.

Create a project called "StackOverflowTests" (so you don't have to change anything) and paste this code in your Window1.xaml file. Should work right out of the box:

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="invisibleButtonTreeViewItemTemplate" TargetType="TreeViewItem" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="19" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!-- Make the ToggleButton invisible -->
            <ToggleButton IsChecked="False" Visibility="Hidden" ClickMode="Press" Name="Expander" />
            <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}" Name="Bd" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Grid.Column="1">
                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding HeaderedContentControl.Header}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderedContentControl.HeaderTemplate}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderedItemsControl.HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header" Name="PART_Header" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
            </Border>
            <ItemsPresenter Name="ItemsHost" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <!-- Remove this trigger so it does not collapse on double click or-->
            <!--<Trigger Property="TreeViewItem.IsExpanded">
                <Setter Property="UIElement.Visibility" TargetName="ItemsHost">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <x:Static Member="Visibility.Collapsed" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Trigger.Value>
                    <s:Boolean>False</s:Boolean>
                </Trigger.Value>
            </Trigger>-->
            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.HasItems">
                <Setter Property="UIElement.Visibility" TargetName="Expander">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <x:Static Member="Visibility.Hidden" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Trigger.Value>
                    <s:Boolean>False</s:Boolean>
                </Trigger.Value>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="TreeViewItem.IsSelected">
                <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="Bd">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DynamicResource ResourceKey="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DynamicResource ResourceKey="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Trigger.Value>
                    <s:Boolean>True</s:Boolean>
                </Trigger.Value>
            </Trigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="TreeViewItem.IsSelected">
                        <Condition.Value>
                            <s:Boolean>True</s:Boolean>
                        </Condition.Value>
                    </Condition>
                    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive">
                        <Condition.Value>
                            <s:Boolean>False</s:Boolean>
                        </Condition.Value>
                    </Condition>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="Bd">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DynamicResource ResourceKey="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DynamicResource ResourceKey="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </MultiTrigger>
            <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled">
                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DynamicResource ResourceKey="{x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Trigger.Value>
                    <s:Boolean>False</s:Boolean>
                </Trigger.Value>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">

        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource invisibleButtonTreeViewItemTemplate}" />
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>
<TreeView>
    <TreeViewItem Header="Item 1" IsExpanded="True">
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item 1.1" IsExpanded="True" />
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item 1.2" IsExpanded="True">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Item 1.2.1" IsExpanded="True" />
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeViewItem>
    <TreeViewItem Header="Item 2" IsExpanded="True">
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item 2.1" IsExpanded="True" />
    </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this recently. On the TreeView control I just set:

```
IsHitTestVisible="False"
```

and added into my app.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
</Style>
```

Though this removes the ability to select any of the TreeViewItems.
I just did it because I wanted the simple hierachical representation of some data I had.