# Create Tabbed Sidebar with sections WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-controls, controls

I'm trying to create a tabbed sidebar with sections, like the following in WPF. There are a few approaches that I have considered, but is there a simpler and more elegant way to do it?

**Approach 1: ListBox**

Using a `ListBox` and binding SelectedItem to a value, which the content control on the right binds to. To differentiate between the header and the sections, I use a DataTemplate selector.

---

**Approach 2: RadioBUtton/Check Boxes / ToggleButtons**

Using radiobuttons, I bind the selected item to the content control. However, due to the WPF bug, I will have to link them together using value converters.

---

[image: Tabbed Interface Split into Sections]

[image]

Comment: If your sidebar is hierarchical, why not use a TreeView instead of ListBox in Approach1?

Comment: Are you able to disable expanding/collapsing of  the treeview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a little more styling to this and I think it could work pretty well

```
    <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left">
        <TabControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TabItem" x:Key="SideBarSectionStyle">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGreen" />
            </Style>
        </TabControl.Resources>

        <TabItem Header="Section A" Style="{StaticResource SideBarSectionStyle}" />
        <TabItem Header="Tab Item 1" IsSelected="True" />
        <TabItem Header="Tab Item 2" />
        <TabItem Header="Tab Item 3" />
        <TabItem Header="Tab Item 4" />
        <TabItem Header="Tab Item 5" />
        <TabItem Header="Section B" Style="{StaticResource SideBarSectionStyle}" />
        <TabItem Header="Tab Item 6" />
        <TabItem Header="Tab Item 7" />
        <TabItem Header="Tab Item 8" />
        <TabItem Header="Tab Item 9" />
    </TabControl>
```

Comment: Why did I not think of <TabItem IsEnabled="False"></TabItem>

Answer (score 1):

Here are some more ideas:

1. (Probably the most ideal) Use a treeview and template the parents and children to hide the expand button. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361243/treeview-hide-buttons) should help you figure out how to hide them.
2. Instead of using 1 listbox, use several listboxes with each representing a different category of options. You can use the same template or different ones if you want. Also, I would keep the header out of the listbox and have it be a Label or whatever that sits above the list view. You could adjust the margin on the list box to get that parent/child indention like the tree view.