# Need help to prepare Main Home Page for WPF application having vertical menu

Tags: asp.net, wpf, windows

[image]

Hii, 
I am creating a WPF aplication. My home page will look like the one I have shown in the image. 
In which i will have following componenents:
1. Topbar
2. Left bar - slide down menu like accordion which will slide down on selection if it has any submenu items otherwise on selection it will show related form.
3. Main panel - in which i will open my child forms 
4. Bottom bar.

I would prefer if i get already implemented application that i can reuse in my application, as I think this form is gonna take hell lot of time. And Also as **I am new to WPF**, I would love to have some guidance about following points

1. How to make a slide down accordion like menu in WPF, which are also supposed to have submenu in it. ex. Report menu - will have list of all reports in it, which will be displayed when you click on the reports menu. How can I accomplish this in WPF>
2. How to open child form in right side panel? What controls/components should I use in my form to host child forms?
3. Any sample applications, web references, or already implemented code will be of great help as I have very strict deadline and dont afford to spend much time in exploring.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create Tabbed Sidebar with sections WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014796/create-tabbed-sidebar-with-sections-wpf)

Comment: @Merlyn : Thanks. it provides some information about how to proceed with left bar. But need some more basic information about how to proceed with entire form.

Comment: @GirishK: That solution will definitely solve 1 and 2, and there is a sample in one of the answers.  The content of your pages can be user controls if you want separate XAMLs for each page.  As for the rest (how to get content in a tab page), just check out a tutorial on tab pages, like this one: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/the-wpf-tab-control-inside-and-out

Comment: @Merlyn : Yes, it has really given me some approach to try out with. Just wondering, how will I be able to provide slide down approach to the tabs. Any ideas on this??

Comment: @GirishK: As in, display more UI between buttons, inside the tab bar, when one of the tabs is selected?  That gets a little hairier.  You could cheat and use a tree view, with custom code to ensure only one tree is expanded at a time.  You could also use the accordian from the WPF toolkit (http://wpf.codeplex.com/).  I'd be careful with that, though, as some of the WPF toolkit controls (data grid in particular) was a nasty beast to try to work all of the bugs out of (2 years ago when I had to test an app that used it).

Comment: @Merlyn : I tried accordion in sample app, and working fine. But somehow I am not entirely convinced. I Will try treeview with tabitems also. And merlyn, is there not any other sample app, references anywhere on the net as this is the most common task we all have to do when starting a new project??

Comment: @GirishK: Well, the treeview is actually a no-go unless you're okay with more than one accordion page being open at once.  It's possible to get it to work in an accordion-like way, but it will be a pain to get styling to work correctly (to remove the drop-down arrow, since that arrow breaks any "single tree selected" logic)

Comment: @Merlyn: Well. for now going with tab bar. Later On will think about how to provide slide down effect. Will do some custom coding if necessary. Between please let me know if you come up with any other approach.

Comment: @GirishK: Added my attempts at re-purposing the tree view as an answer.  It's fairly involved, but I think the approach will work, depending on how long you want to invest in it.  Otherwise you might want to look into an existing UI library, since they tend to look really glossy "off the shelf", and tend to provide a lot of (easier) customizability.

Comment: @Merlyn : Thanks merlyn, currently have prepared simple  menu with tabs without slide down functionality. Thanks again for taking some time out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Abandon full accordion functionality**

If you can live without a full accordion, you could easily accomplish something similar to what you want by using a `TabControl`, with alternate layout (`TabStripPlacement="Left"`).

See this question (the same as in my comments):  [Create Tabbed Sidebar with sections WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014796/create-tabbed-sidebar-with-sections-wpf)

**Existing Library**

There are existing WPF control libraries with accordions:

- [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/)
- Telerik Rad controls - http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf.aspx (or silverlight/asp.net MVC, etc)
- Many others, most of them for money...

**DIY**

You can try using a [`TreeView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeview.aspx) to implement your accordion, too.  You just need a few tricks up your sleeve to accomplish this:

First, you need to hide the tree-view buttons.  They will mess up what we're trying to accomplish.  See this question - [Treeview hide [+] [-] buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361243/treeview-hide-buttons)

Second, you want to ensure that the `IsExpanded` property is set to true if a `TreeViewItem` or one of its children is selected, and set to false otherwise.  You can do this with a `IMultiValueConverter` combined with a `Style` for `TreeViewItem`.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">

<!-- ... -->

<TreeView>
  <TreeView.Resources>
    <local:SelectedItemToIsChildConverter x:Key="isChildConverter" />
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
      <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="IsExpanded">
          <Setter.Value>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource isChildConverter}">
              <Binding Path="SelectedItem"
                RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeView}}" />
              <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
            </MultiBinding>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </Style.Setters>
    </Style>
  </TreeView.Resources>
  <!-- Children here, or set ItemsSource property via databinding -->
</TreeView>
```

Here's the code for the converter, in separate CS file:

```
public class SelectedItemToIsChildConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        TreeViewItem selectedItem = values.Length > 0 ? values[0] as TreeViewItem : null;
        TreeViewItem targetItem = values.Length > 1 ? values[1] as TreeViewItem : null;

        if (targetItem == null)
            return false;

        TreeViewItem currentItem = selectedItem;
        while (currentItem != null)
        {
            if (currentItem == targetItem)
                return true;
            currentItem = currentItem.Parent as TreeViewItem;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

After this, you would have to style it to make it look nice, and support animation.

Once this is all done, use a grid to split up your UI.  Use data binding to show content on your main UI area, based off the selected tree view item.

**Edit:**

Actually, a tree view is a poor base for an accordion.  I searched a bit for details on accordion controls, and it turns out that they tend to only have one level of hierarchy.

With this description in mind, it may be easier to use a `DataGrid`, and take advantage of the `RowDetails` to expand your accordion view.

Here's a brief tutorial: http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html#rowDetails

Just make sure most of the data grid features are disabled.